# Vue.js Fetch throws 404 and api response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't make a POST request in Vue.js. It was giving me CORS issues, but I added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

to the API and they went away. I can get valid responses from the API using Postman while using the same email and password (Postman ignores CORS).

Here is my Fetch request:

```
<script>
export default {
data () {
    return {}
},
methods : {
    login : function () {
        console.log('Logging in');
        // axios({
        //     method : 'post',
        //     url : 'https://www.example.com/login',
        //     headers : {'content' : 'application/json'},
        //     data : {
        //         email : 'emailHere',
        //         password : 'passwordHere'
        //     }
        // })
        // .then(function (response) {
        //     console.log(response);
        // })
        // .catch(function (error) {
        //     console.log(error);
        // });

        fetch('https://www.example.com/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email : 'emailHere',
                password : 'passwordHere'
            })
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))

    }
}
}
</script>

https://www.example.com/api/v1/authenticate/login 404 (Not Found)
{status: false, message: "Invalid credentials"}
```

I tried Axios, and still gives me 404, but not the "Invalid Credentials" response.

In other applications I have used jquerys ajax successfully with the same API, so the API seems to allow javascript requests. But Fetch and Axios don't like it.

I have a Login.vue component that has a button

```
<a id="login-btn" @click.prevent="login">{{ $t('loginPage.loginButtonText') }}</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `Content-Type` header. Try setting headers in your request. `Fetch` demands that you set headers explicitly since it is a low-level API. Your server may reject as it doesn't recognize appropriate `Content-Type`. Try this:

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/login', {
    method: 'POST',

    // THIS IS IMPORTANT
    headers: new Headers({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json',
    }),

    body: JSON.stringify({
        email : 'emailHere',
        password : 'passwordHere'
    })
})
```

Also, remember two things with `fetch`:

First getting 404 using fetch doesn't mean that your request has failed. If a server responds 4xx or 5xx error, then fetch is considered successful. Only when a network error occurs, fetch is rejected. **So if you get 404, it means the request has reached server but there is a problem with the client side.**

Second, try setting `mode` to `cors` [in you fetch request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Thought the default value of `mode` is `cors`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried both individually and together, gives a different response but still 404.

Comment: I included jquery in the index file and made an ajax POST request with same params. It worked as expected and returned a response with data. $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.example.com/login', 
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            email : 'emailHere',
            password : 'passwordHere'
          },
          success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
          }
      });

Comment: Here is the response from your suggestion. Failed to load https://www.example.com/login: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404. TypeError: Failed to fetch.

Comment: @BrianBarton, That is strange. Need to think why that could be happening.

Comment: Any others thoughts?

Comment: @BrianBarton, Cannot suggest anything at a moment. Things look perfectly fine.